# Can't get LAME to compile in JNI Android

Tags: android, java-native-interface, native, lame

I have been following this tutorial http://developer.samsung.com/android/technical-docs/Porting-and-using-LAME-MP3-on-Android-with-JNI, however I dont seem to get it to compile when it comes to Compilation with NDK section. The following is the error that I get

Android NDK: WARNING: APP_PLATFORM android-17 is larger than android:minSdkVersion 7 in ./AndroidManifest.xml 
[armeabi] Compile thumb : mp3lame <= bitstream.c
jni/./libmp3lame/bitstream.c:33:18: fatal error: lame.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make.exe: *** [obj/local/armeabi/objs/mp3lame/./libmp3lame/bitstream.o] Error 1

Answer (score 0):

I have added

```
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += jni/include
```

to Android.mk, so it can find the ".h" needed.

Comment: btw if you want to use the wrapper.c in samsung tutorial, fix the include of lame.h too